# I need help figuring out what type of programmer can do what I have in mind

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Id like to make a program based off data taken from a video stream. Sort of how the Chinese company SenseTime can track cars and people. I know I need a back and front end programmer for the main program but I do not know much about extracting and tracking data from the video feed. Im guessing id need a programmer that knows about machine learning, neural networks, & computer vision?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct.  A "Data Scientist" is someone who will have experience in this field.  Someone with a specialty in computer vision and convolutional neural networks.